# Is there a name for Stack Overflow users as a whole?

Tags: discussion

When referencing the abstract notion of "all users of Stack Overflow", is there an existing term in use? If not, would you think it should be Stack Overflowers, or maybe Stack Overflovians? Maybe drop the assumed "Stack" and just use Overflowers or Overflovians?

I think that "Overflovian" sounds more fanciful, but it has the benefit of also being an adjective (as in "that comment was not very Overflovian") whereas the equivalent adjective form of Overflower would be Overflowerly or Overflowerish.

Comment: What about *users*?

Comment: Users in the 286,071 reputation bracket are commonly called "Infallible awesome super elite". Other than that, there is no common word for Stack Overflow's users. Nothing wrong with calling them just that.

Comment: @Pekka웃: So, what about 286,081 rep users?

Comment: @Cebrus them? Total losers.

Comment: You're at your rep cap for today, ain't ya?..

Comment: @PatrickHofman I was about to suggest that, but that makes my addiction sound a lot worse that I want it to.

Comment: @Cebrus probably not - I rarely hit it these days (nor should I, I hardly do anything anymore except comment and vote to close). Fingers crossed there'll be two votes in a row!

Comment: My thought is that "users of Stack Overflow" is too literal. Whereas most of the time literal is what we are going for, that is fine - I am just wondering if there may be another term in the more conceptual sense. For instance, in the literal sense of the term no American citizen could ever do something "un-American" by definition, yet the term is used in the conceptual sense all the time.

Comment: @Pekka웃, by your words, you're now a _"Total Loser"_. Not for long though, probably...

Comment: Just plain "SO users".  Boring but accurate.

Comment: @HansPassant sometimes it is useful to be inaccurate or ambiguous. For instance, after an SO Moderator election - if you said "The SO Users have spoken" then you would be using this "accurate" term in an inaccurate way - as it is unlikely that all SO Users have cast a ballot.

Comment: How bout Stackers? Shortened for Stack Users ;)

Comment: @OpuLance I like it, but wouldn't that refer to the entire Stack Exchange community?

Comment: Ex-perts, vamps and whores, you'd hear it from the people of the town; they'd call us experts, vamps and whores; but every night all the lost would come around, and lay their questions down...

Comment: @OpuLance: So far, I never saw someone calling SO users _Stackers_, but I read about _Sticklers_ from time to time ;)

Comment: There was an old Meta.SO (now Meta.SE) post about this that I can't find right now. I always liked the "Stack Over Flowers" (or, to modernize it, "Stack Over s") proposal there.

Answer (score 12):

No, there is no term  that is commonly accepted as a valid demonym* beyond the various variations of "users of Stack Overflow".

<sub>* = yeah, I know it's probably not the perfectly correct term. If you know better, edit it.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, maybe not the right word but Demonym was the idea I was going for.

Comment: Oh.  I though we were all called stackers.  I even had t-shirts made :-(

Comment: @NathanOliver you misheard, it was *slackers*

Comment: @Pekka웃 Ah.  Damn my ears.

Answer (score 12):

The reason such a term does not exist is because using Stack Overflow is not something that makes up part of our *identity*.

There are names for people who live in or were born in Germany, for example, because this is an important part of their identity. They have a meaningful group identity, so we can and do refer to them collectively as Germans. Sometimes these exist for other, lower-level locations as well, like cities and towns. Residents of Chicago might identify as Chicagoan. Sociologically, these are called [demonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym).

There are also terms that refer to people's occupation/profession, like "doctor," "lawyer," and "programmer." Since people are often grouped together (I hesitate to say *united*) by their work, the same terms are used for all practitioners of the craft. We are all programmers. By extension, similar terms have been coined to refer to fanatics or devotees of a particular hobby, like Trekkies (fans of Star Trek). Or "bloggers."

People who use a website on the Internet do not generally define their identity around that site, so there is no collective term to refer to them. (For those few who *do* define their identity around a website, well, we prefer not to encourage them.)

"Users" is the correct word, but when not used in context, it needs a bit of extra qualification: "Stack Overflow users" or "users of Stack Overflow" are both appropriate. If you don't like the term users, you could also call us "contributors." If you want to be even more specific, you can refer to an *action*: "askers" and "answerers" both exist on this site.

Comment: Even though it may not typically be part of *our* identity, the Stack Overflow community has various characteristics which comprise its own identity. For instance actions within the site can be judged as to how well they fit within "the goals and ethics of the community" or "in fitting with the standard practices of the community" and so on. An adjective form of a demonym conveys all these things in fewer words.

Comment: YouTubers? Surely there is more to calling someone a "doctor" than that they are "grouped together"? You presume that people born in a particular place "define their identity" in a particular way, lock-step, no choice. Indeed you seem to give identify itself great importance, whilst providing a recipe for how someone should make their own... according to the rules.

Answer (score 3):

From the [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour):

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for ***professional and enthusiast programmers***

---

We're a *community*, not a cult. We don't need a collective name that differentiates us from any other programmer or community because Stack Overflow is about **in**clusion.

Comment: I don't disagree with any of your points but they are non-sequitur. Given that Stack Overflow is about inclusion - under the circumstance that one SO user tried to bully another SO user away from the site, one might describe that as being highly un-Overflovian behavior. Having a name for a group of people neither causes that group to be exclusive or a cult.

Comment: @EthanCabiac I would argue that a more general term of 'un-friendly' or 'un-social' would suffice - not bullying someone isn't a typical characteristic specific to a Stack Overflow user, it's just expected as a functioning member of a society. There isn't a set of behavioral characteristics that define a Stack Overflow user, so I wouldn't use a term specific to the site to describe a user's behaviour either.

Comment: _"Overflovian"_ sounds very... "Fanboy" to me. We're just a bunch of _users_. Instead of _un-Overflovian_, one could call that behavior _impolite_.

Comment: A fair point, but the extra specificity adds more information. "Unfriendly" or "unsocial" accurately describe the behavior, - but "un-Overflovian" provides the extra context that such behavior isn't welcome here.

Comment: I think a ban from the site is just as clear ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Yea, there is.

### Programmers

<sup><sub>(Sadly, not all programmers can actually code.)</sub></sup>

My point is: We're all just a bunch of users. We don't need no special names.

Comment: But then how do we distinguish between SO and Programmers.SE users?

Comment: Sadly, there's no single word for that, in the terminology of this day and age.

Comment: Why would we need to? If you needed to reference all users of SO, well, there you go. "Users of SO"

Comment: [Programmer *(noun)*](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2RXQF.jpg)