# Can we talk about the reviewing culture here on Meta?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close, meta, vote-to-delete

Kind of related to [Can we talk about the voting culture here on Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta), but that one is about downvoting. I want to talk about close-voting and delete-voting. For quite some time I noticed that there is a group of people on Meta who vote to close any question they don't like as off-topic, choosing varying reasons that don't actually apply. Then, after the question gets closed, the delete-votes pile up.

This results in questions asked by well-meaning but perhaps ill-informed users to be downvoted into oblivion, close-voted before someone can answer and delete-voted within the first hour of its existence. *I* interpret this as *"We don't want your kind here, go away"*, which is not nice to users who genuinely want feedback or discussion. I also addressed this in [my answer in 'Meta to new user: your question is a turd that cannot be polished (or: we need to Be Nice here too)'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333956/266143).

I'm going to have to reconstruct the history I have with this issue from my flagging history to provide some backstory.

1. Seven months ago there was this question: [Is [discussion] allowed on meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318130/is-discussion-allowed-on-meta). I flagged it at the moment it had two "cannot reproduce" close-votes, which were ridiculously inapplicable. My flag was considered "helpful" and the close-votes were invalidated by a moderator. The question is now closed as "does not seek input and discussion", which is fine, as the OP seemed to want to post a rant instead of starting a discussion.
2. Then there was [Is there a name for Stack Overflow users as a whole?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318195/is-there-a-name-for-stack-overflow-users-as-a-whole). It was closed as "off-topic". Then it was reopened by five users. And closed as "opinion-based" again. I flagged, flag was marked "helpful", a mod opened the question again.
3. After that I flagged [Who is a moderator ? Are they an employee of SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318765/who-is-a-moderator-are-they-an-employee-of-so), because there were "non-repro" votes again. Sure, it might be a silly question, but that doesn't warrant close-voting with random close reasons as far as I'm concerned. This time, the flag was declined: *"The user appears to be voting properly. The example you gave is a terrible question that should definitely have been closed. Perhaps you should review https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta"*
4. Next question from my flagging history: [Question has the answer, right after the 3rd edit. Why wasn't it noticed by future edits/mods?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322828/question-has-the-answer-right-after-the-3rd-edit-why-wasnt-it-noticed-by-futu). The close-voters interpreted the question incorrectly, and picked the wrong duplicate. My flag was marked "helpful", but the question remains closed as an incorrect duplicate.
5. Then there was this *"Is this on-topic for Stack Overflow?"* question: [Where can I ask: Lotus Notes 8.5 Not Supporting Digital Badging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/9372). Initially I close-voted because it looked like a question that should have been posted to Main, but it was edited after which I retracted my close-vote. Yet it was robo-close-voted. My flag was marked "helpful", no visible action taken. Took quite some time to go through the reopen queue.
6. [I should be allowed to answer closed questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326227/i-should-be-allowed-to-answer-closed-questions) was again one of those cases where close-votes appeard to be abused as "I strongly disagree" votes, which is not what they are for. After two declined flags because I wasn't verbose enough, the third flag was marked "helpful" and one hour after closing it, it was reopened and remains open.
7. [Serial voting still showing on my questions 5 days after incident, cache not cleared as expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335785/serial-voting-still-showing-on-my-questions-5-days-after-incident-cache-not-cle) closed as duplicate without reading or understanding the question.

I hope the pattern is clear now.

Now **the problem** that I'd like to discuss: it appears to me that an small crowd of 5-10 *relatively* low-rep (5K-20K) people are active in the review queues on Meta, and they are down-, close- and delete-voting everything that they don't like, while they (again, this is how it appears to me) hardly ever participate posting actual answers on Main.

Do we want a group that small determine what gets discussed on Meta? Do they have the right to close-vote with whatever reason they seem fit, without even trying to (or at least in some cases failing to) understand what's actually being asked in some cases, and delete-voting it so only a small group gets to read what gets posted here on a daily basis?

Alright, an edit to more expressively clarify my concerns: it appears that there are a couple of users who grind the close and reopen queue, where the tendency of voting hangs towards "close" or "leave closed" or even "delete", while the questions and their comments don't appear to be read that attentively.

Comment: And of course, as is tradition: possible duplicate of [Can we talk about the voting culture here on Meta?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta) (no, it isn't).

Comment: In the linked questions, there might be inappropriate closing, but I don't see any examples of inappropriate deletion. All of the examples never were deleted (apart from 1 where it is the OP that deleted), and do not have delete votes that I can see.

Comment: @Tunaki you're right about that. Unfortunately I couldn't find any recent examples of questions that I found inappropriately deleted, but it's not like it doesn't happen.

Comment: FWIW, with regards to #7 (serial voting), I casted my Close Vote before someone pointed out that, in the comments of the answer in the duplicate question, there was some information indicating that #7 was not a duplicate, but a bug instead. So don't automatically assume that someone has malintent :)

Comment: @Stijn yes, mistakes can be made. One close-vote does not make a difference. That question however mentions _"this happend some weeks ago"_ (so, beyond any reasonable caching issues, refuting the duplicate), and a couple of the people I'm (not explicitly) addressing with this question closed that question from the review queue without reading it nor its comments.

Comment: Personally I kinda get the feeling that sometimes many users on meta just think they have to make a (close) vote on every question and if the question isn't super good it gets a downvote/close-vote. I think more users should know that many times you don't have to vote. If a new user asks a normal question about how something on SO works then you don't have to vote if you neither find it very good for an upvote or so bad that you would downvote. And in such situations I think many users on meta just think they have to vote and downvote and or close vote.

Comment: Do beware the Pareto distribution, almost every activity at SE obeys that law.  The only other pattern to look for that I can think of is the effect of chat rooms, they tend to vote as a block.  I don't see a real problem otherwise, voting velocity on meta is very high, both to close and to re-open.

Comment: I kind of dislike the way you judge experience of users purely by the reputation on the main site. Even 5k is not too low.

Comment: @vaultah note the word "relatively".

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't see that word in *"such inexperienced users (according to reputation)"*.

Comment: @vaultah I don't like repetition. You can't pick apart singular sentences from a story. I'm sorry that you don't like it, but it's my opinion, my observations. Also, the users I'm trying to address by that don't actively participate on Main and haven't increased their reputation  significantly over the time I've watched this behavior.

Comment: @Hans the problem here on Meta is that the handful of users who grind the close queue are the same who tick off items off the reopen queue, meaning once closed often remains closed.

Comment: I am kind of disappointed to not see a close vote on this post ;)

Comment: Hard to imagine that the review queues play much of a role on meta.  Other than that it easy to see who votes, organic voting is much harder to track.  They matter much more SO due to the low view counts, meta posts never had a lack of views.  106 on this one already :)

Comment: @vaultah Reputation is a rather inaccurate judge of experience and skill as a programmer, but it's actually quite accurate as a measure of amount of time spent participating with the site, and knowledge of how *the site works*, which is what CodeCaster is using it as a proxy for here.

Comment: [Another recent example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333480/176646). The OP actually had to post a [separate Meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333494/176646) to find out why his unpopular but on-topic answer was deleted.

Comment: @Servy I was mostly referring to people who participate in review queues and editors. They don't get reputation for what they do, but I'm pretty sure they know the culture and rules of the site quite well. Labelling them as inexperienced *only* because they don't have popular answers to get steady reputation income from doesn't feel right to me. If you disagree with this, that's fine.

Comment: I suck at SQL, but if someone could dig around SEDE and find out how often this is happening, I think that would be valuable input into the discussion, if only for how quickly we can expect moderators to respond...

Comment: @CodeCaster which question should I be answering?  The original "_Do we want a group that small, of such inexperienced users (according to reputation), determine what gets discussed on Meta?_" or the revised "_it appears that there are a couple of users who grind the close and reopen queue [poorly]_"?  Those questions have much different scopes.

Comment: @ryanyuyu good point, the latter is more what I tried to convey. I didn't deem the reviewing important enough to mention at first. I can't really edit the question properly at the moment, will try a title fix.

Comment: @CodeCaster If it really is only a handful of users, the best thing might be to deal with them individually somehow, in the context of our current guidelines. Re-educate, or ban? I wouldn't reach for a culture adjustment unless it's a recurring (with different groups of users) or prevalent issue (lots of users). (Nor am I recommending any course of action, just making an observation about your question.) NB: I didn't follow the links, but am reading your implication "in-crowd of 5-10..."

Comment: Let me see if this isn't a case of *I want to see a pattern* for something I don't like. [This SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/560562/users-by-number-of-closed-questions) shows (for non-deleted questions) the users with their close, reopen, delete, undelete counts. Now I think I see the users you're after in that list *but* I also see the usual suspects. Isn't the lower traffic on meta a much larger contributor to what you see?

Comment: @rene if that appears to be the case, I'll happily admit it. I'm not here to shame users, but to see _if_ there is a pattern of abusing privileges, and if so, how we can educate people to prevent that. I only mentioned my observations to aid the discussion, a mere _"I don't like the voting on Meta"_ wouldn't have been received this well. That being said, could you write an equal query that operates on deleted posts?

Comment: @rene you should put there those that are closed by /review vs organic closing. That way you will see *the* pattern...

Comment: @Braiam I did [here for close votes](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/560727) and I'm still not convinced based on the statistics. That is to say: I'm not convinced that there is a lack of enough users to counter any negative effects the couple of users that curate meta by means of the CVQ.

Comment: @Servy I would contend that reputation has almost no correlation after 200 with the experience in how the site works. There are some utterly clueless (when it comes to policy and moderation) 100k users on this site.

Comment: @rene oh, there's no lack of users that can reopen stufff, but once you close a question, unless it is edited it basically lost all exposure it could get which would advert any measure of apathy. BTW, we have enough users to deal with the close queue on main, yet it grows ;)

Comment: @rene - Your query is inaccurate and should not be considered for discussion here. All of my close votes are organic, and the SEDE result shows only 4, with 52 being from the queue. However, I do not use the queue to close, especially not on meta.

Comment: @Magisch - I disagree. A 100k rep user is 100% more likely to understand the way the site is intended to work when compared to someone with 200 reputation.

Comment: @TravisJ yeah, I have already made a request to a CM to get data that is sound. It counts you in the queue camp if a question was closed by you but also had a reviewtask. That is all SEDE has to offer.

Comment: @rene - It was a good try. However, I think that the main issue is still the review tasks you mention, which is the topic of this discussion as well. Braiam makes some good points below in his answer in those regards. Perhaps a more thought generating point to make would be, why do we even need a review queue on meta? I suppose to help with old questions being closed. There is certainly enough traffic to deal with the closure of new questions.

Comment: Wait, you're now only observing this on *Meta*?! Can't wait for the moment where people will finally realize this has been happening on the main site for at least some 2-3 years now...

Comment: "Now the problem that I'd like to discuss: it appears to me that an small crowd of 5-10 relatively low-rep (5K-20K) people are active in the review queues on Meta, and they are down-, close- and delete-voting everything that they don't like" ... Very simple. Create your own group to fight the assumedly evil impact of this group by upvoting, reopen-voting and flagging deliberately wrongly chosen close votes for moderator attention (if only they would be displayed for all close voters - problem there). In the end it's a simple who watches the watchmen problem, isn't it?

Comment: @Trilarion ain't nobody got time for that. I'm not here to organize a mob to counter incorrect voting, I'm trying to raise awareness for the incorrect voting in the first place.

Comment: @CodeCaster Some people seem to resist to the very idea that "[raising] awareness for the incorrect voting" is important. I wonder why that happens. Perhaps it is just a matter of an overly individualistic mindset ("everyone is free to make their individual choices about how to vote", etc.).

Comment: @duplode "Some people seem to resist to the very idea that "[raising] awareness for the incorrect voting" is important." Just in case you would mean for example me. No, I'm not against it but I also don't think the goal will be achieved. In short, I think it's a waste of time. All arguments are known already. So those who vote incorrectly will most probably give a damn about what has been said here and will just continue. I mentioned a possible solution. If nobody has time for it or any other effective solution then my prediction is that nothing will change. It's nice to try to educate people.

Comment: @Trilarion Now that you expanded on your position, it is indeed clear that you are not against it (your stance about the matter appears to be pessimistic, rather than individualistic). Still, thinking that raising awareness is a waste of time also amounts to thinking that it isn't important. I believe your position is far more defensible than the individualistic one, but it seems to me that both point towards the same direction -- the degeneration of community standards to the lowest common denominator.

Comment: @duplode "...the degeneration of community standards to the lowest common denominator." That depends. If incorrect voting is contagious and nobody else becomes really active against it, then this may happen. I think it's not that bad, most probably we will remain in an intermediate state. It's nice to try to educate people but the gains are usually very, very low. You can point toward the stars, but you should also be aware that very likely you won't reach them by preaching alone.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've noticed this a lot more too, and I'm working (in whatever spare time I have nowadays) to craft a few SEDE queries to see how frequently a post is voted to be deleted on Meta to see if it's really necessary.

Let me state my opinion here so that it's clear.

I believe that it's fair game to downvote a question here on Meta, especially if it's not an ideal approach to a problem, is ill-researched, or is just plain ranty, but I don't really like deletion of questions here unless it's *absolutely* necessary.  Save for users mistaking* the site for Stack Overflow, there are ***very few questions*** which actually need to be deleted.

In that regard, it's also not a bad thing if we get a few more gold-badge holders in the three key tags we have here.  Giving more people the ability to undo a bad dupe can only be a good thing, and I hope that others will soon gain that privilege.

I'll address your concerns in turn; I largely agree with them, and I do hope I'm not contributing to the issue.  At least, I don't *think* I am...

> ...it appears to me that an incrowd of 5-10 relatively low-rep (5K-20K) people are brigading Meta, and they are down-, close- and delete-voting everything that they don't like, while they hardly ever participate on Main. A lot of this action seems to come from the Meta review queues.

<sup>Ah, how enviable it must be to consider 5K-20K reputation "low"...</sup>

I don't disagree that there is an in-crowd of users doing this kind of thing, but I will disagree with the other two parts.

- Users here *heavily* participate on Main, especially considering that Stack Overflow's reputation is the exact same as Meta Stack Overflow's reputation.
- The review queues here are *very* hard to really gain any traction in; I'm inclined to believe that these actions are taken *outside* of the queue, especially considering that the users who fit this profile are normally equipped enough to "handle" the issue themselves.

> Do they have the right to close-vote with whatever reason they seem fit, without even trying to (or at least failing to) understand what's actually being asked in some cases, and delete-voting it so only a small group gets to read what gets posted here on a daily basis?

Close vote with just *whatever* reason?  I'd prefer if they didn't do that but there's no mechanical thing stopping one from doing this; it's up to us as the community to overturn/challenge closures which we feel are unjustified.

If it's genuinely a bad question and it **does** need to be closed, then I really don't see any reason to rearrange the chairs on the *Titanic*.

Deletion, as I mentioned earlier, does strike a bit of a nerve with me in some regards.  As I said before, there aren't that many questions which need to be outright deleted, but there are quite a few which do deserve to be closed or downvoted.  Deletion is one of those things that makes it tougher for a user to either figure out what happened with the comment chain (since comments are no longer accessible through the inbox once a post is deleted), and not enough users know to look through their history to look for it.  Besides that, once the question is deleted, they figure that's pretty much the end of it - they can't get any more input to their problem.

We need to take a more critical look at that and see what's going on there.  I get a sneaking suspicion that more content is being buried in this fashion that shouldn't be.

---

<sup>*:  I'd *love* to give the benefit of the doubt to some users, but for those who ask a coding question on Meta after they've got something like 5 questions on the main site...</sup>

Comment: Very rough SEDE query for [unpopular Meta posts that were deleted and then undeleted](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/539463/unpopular-meta-posts-that-were-deleted-and-then-undeleted). Finding questions that were closed and re-opened would be easier since SEDE can't search posts that are currently deleted.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot:  `PostsWithDeleted` will get you that kind of information.  It just won't generate a link to the post automatically.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea SEDE included deleted posts.

Comment: "The review queues here are very hard to really gain any traction in" enter robo-reviewers.

Comment: @Braiam:  I *genuinely* doubt robo-reviewers are even vying for these queues.  The person with the highest close-vote reviews borders near 3,000.  That's not per quarter; that's *all time*.  The only other person that comes close is shy of 1,800, and even then it starts to taper off.  I won't deny that these people are more on-top of the queues than others would be, but I would doubt they're robo-reviewing.]

Comment: Did you check the /activity of them? For the top one the first 36 pages of all activity are review tasks, 3rd since may doesn't do anything other than review, 6th only has a single edit under it's belt, everything else is review task... robo-reviewers aren't only the ones that review blazing fast (in fact this is not the definition), but that seems to blindly click buttons to get the number to 0!

Comment: As a user with 1.9k +1 for "Ah, how enviable it must be to consider 5K-20K reputation "low"..." and all the rest

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as I interpret it as _"Perhaps we're deleting somewhat too much content from Meta"_. I hope more people read and agree.

Answer (score 4):

> they are <s>down-</s>, *close-* and delete-voting everything that *they don't like*

Is not that they don't like it... if you see their activities pages you will see basically **no activity outside /review** for most of these users! *gasp* Basically, most of the questions you see on the /review/close queue will end up closed one way or another, only the initial close voter had some issue with the question. Other reasons not-withstanding I believe this is fairly bigger problem.

Comment: Where does it say that being active on the site is mandatory before you can use /review?

Comment: @rene I'm rejecting the notion that these people close vote based on "I like/hate this", but simply burning through the queue.

Comment: Sure, and I tend to agree something could be better but your reasoning is flawed, IMHO. I don't think you can link site activity and their usage of /review.

Comment: @rene what reasoning? I'm asserting that since they don't have site activity, they can't come to like/dislike topics! I'm fairly certain that if they disliked those topics as the question hints, they would be more engaged on the site itself which is the only correlation I do. The cherry-picked observation is congruent with this point of view... so long as they are in /review, these users will vote to close them.

Comment: You have some good observations, but there seems to be a highly questionable link between "users are active almost entirely in /review" and "users will blindly vote-to-close anything they see". Can you back that up more?

Comment: @NathanTuggy well, I was almost victim of the later https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/8556 found it from here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29189854#29189854

Comment: I think you make some very good points here.

Comment: @Braiam: Most of the reviews from the first page of each of those users appear to be reasonable, though there are a couple questionable No Repros from John Conde, both of which are probably technically applicable but not necessarily useful. So there might be one blind-closer (although John has a Reopen on the second page), but the other two don't appear to be from what I saw. They just ran across a lot of questions that really do seem to deserve closing.

Comment: @NathanTuggy my point still stands, none of those closures were done by a particular dislike of the topic at hand, since it's more likely that they were roboreviewers.

Comment: @Braiam: Can you distinguish "user is active in a queue and finds a lot of bad posts there" from "user will only ever vote one way in a queue"? Not only have you not done so yet, you seem to be militating against the need for this distinction at all, but you're perfectly comfortable labeling reviewers "robots" without actually demonstrating that they are being careless.

Comment: @NathanTuggy again, you are picking the less relevant part of my answer: **these users do not close questions because they don't like the topic.** It was a direct response to *"I interpret this as "We don't want your kind here, go away", which is not nice to users who genuinely want feedback or discussion."* in OP's question. My point of view offers a more feasible reason why these users act like they do...

Comment: @Braiam: Then why did you mention roboreviewers at all in your answer or comments, including specifically the comment I replied to last? It's sufficient to point out that they hold no personal animosity and are just going through the queue; to suggest that they are doing so clumsily and in bad faith, then refuse to back that assertion up, is unwarranted and rather rude.

Comment: @Braiam: Or, in short: Stop calling people roboreviewers unless you really mean it.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Here is an exhaustive classification of close votes according to the rationale applied by the voter to cast them (1) the rationale follows site policies and community standards; (2) the rationale does not follow said policies and standards; and (3) there is no rationale. The examples mentioned in the question do not fall into (1). The question places them as a case of (2) ("Close it because I don't like it"). Braiam is suggesting (3) (more specifically, the mindlessly-burning-through-the-queue case) is also a plausible classification. That is all there is to this answer.

Comment: @duplode: Okay, but when making accusations of bad-faith reviewing against specific people, it's not enough to say "well maybe they didn't bother to close for any specific reason", you have to actually back that up with some fairly solid evidence that shows that they really made quite a few glaring mistakes that are not simply the result of plausible differences of opinion about how a question fits site policy. And this wild slinging of accusation is entirely unimportant to the answer here, or should be.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Frankly, it is not clear to me how, after pondering about a publicly known activity pattern, saying that someone might be reviewing blindly is any more offensive than saying that someone might be willfully ignoring the community standards while reviewing. The bottom line is that an effective way of avoiding people speculating on Meta about the motives behind one's absurd close votes is not casting absurd close votes in the first place.

Comment: @duplode: The point you're missing is that braiam has refused to actually demonstrate that the close votes were absurd. And, upon checking, they don't appear to be absurd. Maybe you disagree; maybe my check was insufficient. *Make the case.* Again, calling people roboreviewers without actually demonstrating how they are plainly roboting their way through reviews is bad and wrong.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I don't need to demonstrate them, OP's own observations are demonstrating them. I'm just offering a plausible conclusion, that is congruent with observations, yet don't assign malice where you can explain it with ignorance.

Comment: @NathanTuggy The absurd votes I was referring to were those mentioned in this question and the "opinion-based" ones against Braiam's question (the ones that led to your scrutiny), and not the ones you dug out in this thread. In any case, I simply don't see "roboreviewer" as such a grievous insult. If you allow me to speculate, you seem to be acting as if, unless there is proof that whoever Braiam is talking about is *essentially* and always a roboreviewer (and not, say, only in some days of the week), Braiam's comments are an attack on everyone who focuses on reviewing rather than Q&A writing.

Comment: @duplode: No, not really. I'm more focused on the casual accusations of these *particular* users. A roboreviewer is someone you don't want using their moderation privileges because they can't use them right at all. The question asserts that there are a lot of bad reviews for some systemic reason, probably having to do with bad reviewers. I don't (necessarily) disagree with that. It's where specific bad reviewers are identified as being part of a general trend, but without actually demonstrating that they've made more than one or two mistakes.

Comment: @NathanTuggy [1/2] You might have a point about tone. On the other hand, perhaps those accusations you speak of would carry less weight with a more nuanced understanding of bad review*ing* than one grounded in a "roboreviewer" vs. "stellar reviewer" dualism, and I believe Braiam's comments point in that direction.

Comment: [2/2] For instance, here are two conjectures that I find entirely plausible: (1) It is easier to make certain kinds of mistakes, such as carelessly agreeing with bad close votes, while burning through the queues rather than in a more relaxed environment, such as while monitoring a tag looking for questions to answer. (2) Some users, even otherwise competent users, are more prone than others to specific kinds of mistakes, such as carelessly agreeing with bad close votes.

Comment: @duplode: Those are pretty reasonable conjectures, although I'd also note that queues (in my experience, at least) offer an excellent opportunity for shock/outrage at really outstandingly bad actions, such as No Repro votes on a question about moderator status.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I guess we can agree on that the wide assortment of possible poor decisions requires a suitably diverse assortment of places where they can be made visible.

Comment: Well, @NathanTuggy, look at [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/12365): closed as not being about SO, and who were the close voters? You guessed right! The same people I say "they are robo-reviewers"! If that is not robo-reviewing, you care to tell what it is?

Comment: @Braiam I guessed "John Conde, HaveNoDisplayName, and Luke", and was only one-third right. Rhetoric critical success! (Also, a question about an external website? I can easily see how someone might think that's really something that should be asked of them, even though I'd disagree.)

Comment: Hilariously enough I have been blamed for single-handedly closing meta questions because *I* cast the first vote, and I *know* that reviewers on meta don't actually read anything and they just click to close button. Like it's all my fault that meta reviewers don't review stuff to the best of their ability.

Comment: @TinyGiant I've read this comment again today, and I totally missed how hilarious it is... I don't even remember reading it.

Answer (score -5):

> Do they have the right to close-vote with whatever reason they seem fit

In short, yes they have that right.  If they think a close reason fits, they are free to apply a close vote to express that.  While the examples you've pointed to are indeed questionable, many of them did ultimately get reopened.  That means the system is working.  A small clique (if it exists) is not going to determine what meta discusses without the agreement of everyone else on meta.  Your question here is proof of that.

Back here in the real world, I do agree with you that I think that we need to be less lazy here on meta and actually read the questions posted.  The examples you point to, if they are a trend, are certainly bad.  We should close things less aggressively on meta since there are many more eyeballs per post here than on main.  We're not getting flooded, so there's no reason to be close-vote happy.  And we certainly shouldn't use close votes as super-downvotes.

> Alright, an edit to more expressively clarify my concerns: it appears that there are a couple of users who grind the close and reopen queue, where the tendency of voting hangs towards "close" or "leave closed", while the questions and their comments don't appear to be read that attentively.

I'd like to see bad MSO reviews treated the same as regular reviews on SO.  I'm not sure if MSO has review audits (probably not?), but for egregiously poor reviews, perhaps a moderator flag would be appropriate.

But there's a potential problem: I don't know what the penalties are for casting bad close votes on main.  Is there a penalty? Should there be a penalty?  That's why close voting is a reputation-locked privilege and also why other users can undo actions they don't think should have happened.  As far as I know, it takes quite a bit before a bunch of dubious close votes gets to the point of "abuse" for suspensions.  So the rest of meta will just have to stop sitting on their hands and vote more frequently.  Upvotes on discussions that are well-formed and not obviously duplicates will help cut the number of unwarranted close votes.

---

My preferred solution:

I think more community involvement (especially editing) would clear up a lot of these cases.  Even upvotes can help convince other users that a post is worth their time.  Then maybe we'll see fewer bad close votes.  Many of the examples you point to started out rather unclear and close-worthy.  It's hard to tell from the timelines how many close votes accumulated while they were still bad.  So it's entirely possible that only 7 of those close votes are dubious instead of all 35.  Again, let me emphasize that the meta questions that got the best edits were reopened after clarifying edits and comment discussion.

TL;DR

We as a (meta) community should pay more attention to closing things on meta, but it's not currently a bad problem because others are willing to edit and reopen truly on-topic questions.

Comment: "If they think a close reason fits, they are free to apply a close vote to express that." - aren't people supposed to get review-banned for making bad close vote decisions in the review queue? It seems to me like there's a duty to make voting decisions that actually make sense, rather than just slapping "cannot reproduce" votes on posts that aren't even bug reports.

Comment: "many of them did ultimately get reopened. That means the system is working." This sounds like it is the normal way for questions, being closed then reopened... Reopening should be a safety bar, the questions shouldn't have been closed... Mistakes happen, we all know that, but when too many mistakes are made, it is worth asking why are there too many mistakes...

Comment: @user2357112 at the time this post was originally written, the question did not contain allegations of bad MSO reviews.  It was just a (seemingly random) collection of stuff.  I could have just as easily found a similar set of properly closed/deleted MSO questions.  I'll try to address that in a later edit.

Comment: The "system" only works because most people currently agree with the principles it is meant to enforce. Not discussing bad decisions because they are supposedly "not a problem" opens the doors for the principles to be abandoned in a longer time scale. In the "real world", the system is inhabited by people, people create culture, and culture evolves over time.

Comment: @duplode what makes you think we aren't discussing this problem?  My input to this discussion is that it's not a big problem.  Downvote if you disagree, but my answer is most definitely discussing the problem.  I even say as much "_A small clique (if it exists) is not going to determine what meta discusses without the agreement of everyone else on meta. Your question here is proof of that._"

Comment: @ryanyuyu There are many ways of discussing something. In my opinion, the "the system is working, nothing to see here, move along" attitude is a dangerous one, as well as, in extreme cases, a tool for shutting down debate.

Comment: Especially in the context of new users, I'd have to agree with duplode. Once a person has an investment in the ecosystem, and has gained visibility into how things "tend to work," that becomes okay (although non-ideal). But, new users already need thick skin to survive the barrage of downvotes (which new users are more likely to *deserve*) and terse explanations. The question on my mind is, How many quality developers just walk away?

Comment: @jpaugh if you really want people to "survive a barrage of downvotes" edit their post to a good state and then start upvoting.  I think this is much more effective that saying "potential downvoters should think twice."  Anything you can't edit probably should be downvoted for being malformed and unclear.  I think we should attack the problem at the root, which is a pattern of bad meta posts that attract downvotes because of their presentation even if their content is worth an upvote.

Comment: @ryanyuyu. I did not mean to imply that downvotes ought to be withheld; (but I do think the first downvoter should take time to leave a courteous explanations of the downvotes.) My main point was that being a new user is hard enough already.

Comment: Even simple discourtesy can seem like malicious intent over the internet: when the truth is far simpler: many of the people who care about the sites are spread too thinly to consider courtesy a worthwhile use of time.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'd just like to see less apathy.