# Documentation off topic

Tags: discussion, documentation

I added a couple of entries to the Documentation area and they were flagged as being off topic. In fact the reviewer has stated that they are off topic for the Swift Language tag and should be moved or removed.

I have also been told that the "Encryption" tag is not appropriate since the examples are language specific.

The reviewer has stated: "I insist: if you think there's an issue, please post on Meta." So here I am.

The entries were placed under Swift Language tag with titles "AES encryption" and "Key Derivation". See: [PBKDF2](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/7053) and [AES](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/7026).

1. Password Based Key Derivation 2:
   https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/7053
2. AES encryption in CBC mode with a random IV:
   https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/7026

The entries relate to the usage of Apple supplied Common Crypto available to the Swift Language for encryption and key derivation with the Swift Language using the Apple provided Framework available to Swift.

I think the concept that less documentation is better is wrong-headed. Because there is no tag that fits the documentation is still useful, useful and help developers should be the main concern, removing documentation does not help developers.

The questions:

1. Should such documentation be removed?
2. Would removal be in the best interests of developers?
3. How should such issues be resolved?
4. What could be done to solve this type of issue?

Comment: `The reviewer agrees there is no other tag that is acceptable` Not even [tag:ios]?

Comment: Sure, maybe it should be discussed, but probably with links to what you're actually talking about, like we see in the answer. (I'm assuming your comment is about the downvotes.) Re "How should such issues be resolved?", the SO Docs team are working on better venues for discussion (... I think it's per-topic). See the latest update, pinned on the right.

Comment: @zaph:  Noise is noise.  Don't see it any other way than that.

Comment: "if it is a bad question that is what close is for" [On the contrary](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336622/can-we-talk-about-the-reviewing-culture-here-on-meta). (But either way, I don't know what other people are finding bad about this question at all.)

Comment: Meta help  http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta  describes how people should vote. Unfortunatey discussion posts can be treated as feature requests. Some users may be upvoting a useful question, if they are inexperienced in meta culture, and then there is incorrect downvoting to indicate disagreement.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta/272617#272617 The powers that be are powerless but may remain hopeful as the whats meta help topic has not been changed.

Comment: What a great experience interacting with meta folks, you all have been so welcoming, helpful and the discussion has been terrific, that is if down votes are considered discussion. It seems that the consensus is not to be involved in a discussion, not to have helpful content added to the Documentation area but more directed toward the leet clique here having a little fun, that is OK I guess. I will note that there was a minority here that were positive. I will never again darken the hallowed leet halls of meta or adding articles to the Documentation section, helping developers be damned!

Answer (score 12):

I have flagged these articles.

I have also flagged other articles for the same reason: being off-topic in "The Swift Language" section.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/improvement-requests/view/1480

   Here the examples are targeting iOS without explaining that "Basic File I/O" in Swift can also target macOS, Linux, etc. And they are not articles about the Swift language anyway - so, they should be in iOS, not in "Swift".
2. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/improvement-requests/view/5360

   This example is not about Swift, it's rather about Foundation's NSCoding (which is also usable with other languages). NSCoding is not part of Swift.
3. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/improvement-requests/view/3163

   vDSP and vecLib are both subframeworks of the Accelerate Framework, which is available on both iOS and macOS. This has nothing to do with Swift.
4. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/improvement-requests/view/260

   UserDefaults is not related to "The Swift Language" in any way. It is part of Foundation and should be in "iOS" and/or in "macOS".

---

In my opinion, your articles about encryption suffer from the same issue than these ones: they are off-topic for "The Swift Language".

It doesn't mean there's no place for these articles at all in Documentation - and it certainly doesn't mean I want these to be deleted from the Internet.

It simply means that **they are currently off-topic** and therefore should be moved to the right section - this will often be iOS or macOS, but not only.

And if the right section doesn't exist yet, you can create it yourself.

Comment: @zaph [tag:foundation].

Comment: I believe Eric is encouraging you to put it in the [iOS tag on Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/topics), where there seems to be a number of examples using the Swift language.