# "Knee jerk" duplicate flagging and careless rubber stamping doesn't provide optimal service to posters

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I'm a little steamed at this point, so if I appear to be criticizing in a non-constructive way, I apologize.  It's not my intent.  My intent is that I see a problem and I'd like to help fix it.

I was in the middle of answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275834/why-cant-i-input-answer-for-string-ampm-in-main?noredirect=1) question from a beginner OP when it got marked as a duplicate.  Since the code had a case-sensitivity problem, it would error out there, and never have made it to the code that was put forth as a duplicate problem, so the "duplicate" post would be no help to her.  The OP didn't have sufficient experience to explain what kind of error she was getting, instead putting in a variation of the ubiquitous "it doesn't work" sort of answer, and the flagger (obviously) didn't look at the issue very carefully.  "Knee jerk" assessment, in other words, failing to notice the case problem, even after I told him that there were other problems with the OP's code.

What really concerns me, though, is that the moderator who marked it as a duplicate basically rubber-stamped the flagger's assessment.  That suggests institutionalized carelessness.  Not a good look for the site branding-wise, if we add sloppiness to our growing reputation for unfriendliness to newbies.  I get it; some newbies just won't take the trouble to help themselves, but when we don't help the ones that are trying to learn, that's when we start to decline.

There appear to be some users who are looking for reasons to mark questions as duplicates.  It's probably an ego thing; egos are always looking for other egos they can consider stupider than themselves, at least the ones that come on to this site.  Moderators (at least the moderator that marked this one as a duplicate) didn't take the care to see whether the problem was in fact as described, and maybe it's because they aren't looking out for "scalp hunters".

So, am I overreacting (this isn't the first time this has happened) or not?

Comment: ahhh, ajb isn't a mod (atleast i don't see a diamond). when you have a gold tag badge they can use the duphammer for questions that use that tag as it says [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/java) *"These users can single-handedly mark java questions as duplicates and reopen them as needed."*

Comment: So how did ajb mark it as a dup then?  Sorry, didn't understand this properly.

Comment: as the link says ajb earned *"at least 1000 total score for at least 200 non-community wiki answers in the java tag"*

Comment: Oh, I get it.  You're saying that that doesn't make him a moderator.  That helps, but I still don't like it.  :)

Comment: You do know though that "providing optimal service to the poster" isn't the site goal, right? The goal is to create high quality QA, not to help every last one novice who can't use google. The term "Moderator" is a little fuzzy here. Technically speaking, everyone above 15 rep is a moderator. Practicly, we use this term to talk about the (elected) diamond moderators, of which ajb is not one.

Comment: We help newbies by showing them that their problem is not unique.  Pointing them to the canonical answer, vetted by tens of thousands of programmers over many years.  It is not very clear why you don't want to provide that kind of help, maybe it is an ego-thing.  Consider contributing to a forum instead.

Comment: Based on your comment under the linked post you consider it collection of typos and essentially recommending to close as such... That is likely worse than duplicate which at least on surface looks related.

Comment: _"I'm a little steamed at this point"_ Better to take a little break then, go do something else, it at least helps me clear my head so I don't write something up in a rant. - What's intended as a debate quickly becomes a rant when one is angry / annoyed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a useless rant based on misconceptions how Stack Overflow should work.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so [my question changed nothing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336622/can-we-talk-about-the-reviewing-culture-here-on-meta)? Voting to reopen.

Comment: I believe a complete re-write of this question should be made. As-is, there are no questions asked except ranting and baseless accusations. Thus the vote to close.

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't think this falls into the category you mention in your question (let the title alone).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ [oh no?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/12357) The close reason does not apply, and as we speak, there's one delete vote pending. The voting is ridiculous, as usual.

Comment: *The OP didn't have sufficient experience to explain what kind of error she was getting, instead putting in a variation of the ubiquitous "it doesn't work"* - So it should have been closed with the debugging/mcve close reason instead? The dupe at least gives an answer to the question that was asked, even if it doesn't fix every problem with the OP's code.

Comment: What the OP of that question ***really needs*** is to learn how to step through code.  Programmers need to be able to debug their algorithms and determine, at runtime, why things are happening.  If they can't, they're crippled.  They run their programs, wonder why they aren't doing what they expected, and are helpless to do anything about it.  When they come to SO and dump their code into a question, they ask you to do what they cannot, or are not willing to, do.  If it's the second case, they should be shut down for abusing the community. If the first, they need to learn how to debug.

Comment: If there is a canonical "how do I debug my java code" question, it (and others like it) should be closed as a dupe of that.  It would be more helpful than just shutting down the question.

Comment: @Will:  It's not that I disagree in principle, but there are a decent number of facets to Java code which would lead to more broad canonical questions, like the venerable NPE, why Autowired fields are null, or why your Scanner instance doesn't want to read in multiple lines.  I'm personally okay with this particular question being closed as that dupe since it *perfectly* answers the question, but the deletion does feel like salt in a wound there.

Comment: @Tunaki This is a much higher quality rant than most of them. It even asks a question at the end. Seems like it makes sense to reopen this.

Comment: @Will That's a good point.  It would have been nice to be able to share it with the OP.

Comment: @BobRodes:  So now you have a typo (which would still be grounds to close it), and you *still* have the issue with `Scanner` advancing too far after the typo has been fixed.  The compiler would have *quickly* caught the typo, and I'm also more than confident that the true confusion would have lied with the way the scanner advanced rather than an easily interpreted compilation error.  This question wasn't overanalyzed; we simply arrived at the conclusion that the *likely* issue was one with `Scanner.nextLine` as opposed to `new clock`.

Comment: @Makoto It seems clear to me that the compiler had already caught the case sensitivity problem, and that the OP didn't know what to do from there.  Otherwise, she would have already fixed it before posting her code.  If we had voted to close the question as too vague, since she didn't state what error she was getting, I certainly wouldn't have argued, though.  Also, I'm not convinced that case sensitivity issues are the equivalent of typos, since they aren't an issue in all languages and typos are.

Answer (score 26):

The problem is with your perception of our goals. This site doesn't exist to provide the fastest possible solution to everyone who asks a question. It exists to build up a high quality and wide repository of good questions and answers.

For this purpose, many "canonical" very good answers have been given to typical questions. OPs question (sans the typo's) is one of those. The site and future visitors and OP benefit more from reading the thousand-fold refined canonical answer on the subject, rather then something that you (or I, or anyone) could churn out in 5 minutes.

> The OP didn't have sufficient experience to explain what kind of
>   error she was getting, instead putting in a variation of the
>   ubiquitous "it doesn't work" sort of answer, and the flagger
>   (obviously) didn't look at the issue very carefully.

Usually, typo questions are closed as such. But the closing voter probably assumed that they'd figure out the typo soon enough and then would be helped by the duplicate. So you're really debating here whether the question is actually off-topic because it's just a typo (not worth answering according to community guidelines) or a duplicate.

> What really concerns me, though, is that the moderator who marked it
>   as a duplicate basically rubber-stamped the flagger's assessment

The person who closed that question was not a (elected) moderator nor an employee of Stack Exchange. They have earned over 1000 score in over 200 well-received answers on the topic, though, so their judgement as to what is and isn't a duplicate is binding, in this case. Though, 5 members of the community or another user with a gold tag badge could reopen the question just as easily.

All in all, this site isn't for helping out every single newbie. And it isn't for answering a question that has already been answered and peer-reviewed by thousands of developers another dozen times. It's also not for one-on-one tutoring of newbies.

Comment: This is a coherent and reasonable assessment.  However, I don't think of a case sensitivity problem as quite the same thing as a typo, since it isn't true of all languages. Not that I think it's unreasonable to do so, but nor do I see anything in the guidelines that addresses this particular issue one way or the other.  If I'm missing it, please point it out to me.

Comment: Finally, if you have documentation that backs up your last paragraph, please point it out to me as well, so that I may understand that you aren't simply stating your opinion about what "this site isn't for."  Absent the "answering a question that has already been answered" sentence, though.  Obviously the fact of a duplicate flagging mechanism gives credence to that one, and I agree with you on it anyway.

Comment: @BobRodes Maybe [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal)? It's not an authorative reference, but then again, in this community, hardly anything is. The users decide most of the policies and are largely responsible for their enforcement, so a very popular opinion does hold some weight.

Answer (score 4):

I'm as guilty of this as the next newbie, but in blunt language, this is what I understand:

1. This site's highest aim (especially Stack Overflow) is to provide highly vetted answers to Specific questions that aren't addressed elsewhere.  Questions that stand the test of time are the intent.
2. The Rules in the FAQs are not iron clad, they summarize best practices, and if there's uneven treatment, it happens.  (See point 1.)
3. This site is best understood as "right on average" but we all can put our fingers on the scale to sharpen questions and help insure that questions and answers are as impactful as possible.
4. Individual questions that come through are seen as grist for the mill, and if there's good stuff, it rises to the top, and if your question gets answered as it passes by in the flood, you're doing well, if not, try to beef it up to be "print ready" and your odds improve.