# Could we have some statistics on duplicate questions which are then deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, statistics

Since [I want to complete an objective I set out for myself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336648/1079354), but [I can't do it by myself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286495/175248)...

Could we have a dump of statistics concerning posts which are dupehammered, then immediately deleted, on both Meta and Stack Overflow?

I'm asking this since this I've noticed a concerning trend in which questions are suddenly closed as duplicates, then voted to be immediately deleted, and it's unclear to me if the immediate deletion was warranted.

Some of the things I'd like to know about, in general, with positively-scored questions, and negatively-scored questions:

- Average time between duplicate closure and deletion
- Average score of those deleted questions
- Average score of those deleted answers

Comment: I think that how many times the duplicate of the question has been used has also a certain relevance here. There are always some cases where questions from very common duplicates get deleted straightaway, since they add no new value at all and/or are also very poor questions.

Comment: @Rizier123:  Those are the questions I'd expect to be voted a lot lower, and wouldn't have many qualms with them being removed.  However, if they're *not*, that would be a bit concerning.

Comment: That is exactly why I think it is important to know if a question was a duplicate of a  very common duplicate or not, so we can distinguish between the questions which we can delete right away, exactly those from common duplicates, and the other questions which get deleted after closure where we want to investigate and look at the numbers.

Comment: @Rizier123:  I suppose you're asking the *next* question I had, which was...should we even be bothering with these deletions?  If we can extrapolate a pattern for these sorts of questions, and have concrete evidence to suggest that they're not all that great, perhaps that's something else the Roomba can handle?

Comment: Remember that no question that isn't score -3 or lower can be immediately deleted, so if you see dupes being deleted immediately, score allows it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok...

#### Stack Overflow

There've been 246,962 questions closed with a binding vote by *folks who aren't moderators* on Stack Overflow. Of those, 81,189 have been deleted.

For comparison, 12,279 questions have been reopened with a non-mod binding vote, of which 1,602 have been deleted.

Of the dup-closed questions referenced above that were deleted, 1,553 scored more than 0, 27,899 scored 0, and 51,738 scored less than 0.

Here's a table that should answer the rest of your questions:

```
          Closed AvgScore AvgAnswerScore AvgTimeToDeletionInMinutes 
          ------ -------- -------------- -------------------------- 
ZeroScore 27899     0     0.2             271522                     
PosScore   1553   1.6     1.7            68642.5                    
NegScore  51738  -2.2     0.2            41312.1
```

#### Meta Stack Overflow

There've been 2,206 questions closed with a binding vote by *folks who aren't moderators* on Meta Stack Overflow. Of those, 813 have been deleted.

For comparison, 67 questions have been reopened with a non-mod binding vote, of which 10 have been deleted.

Of the dup-closed questions referenced above that were deleted, 16 scored more than 0, 67 scored 0, and 730 scored less than 0.

Breakdown:

```
          Closed AvgScore  AvgAnswerScore AvgTimeToDeletionInMinutes 
          ------ --------- -------------- -------------------------- 
NegScore  730    -7.4        6             29622.3                    
PosScore   16     1.9      1.5              1541.7                     
ZeroScore  67       0       -1             27131.7
```

Comment: It seems like on *average* it's not as big of a deal as I had thought it was, although the deletion of positively-scored duplicates on Meta within two days is a bit shocking.  Are the OPs influencing that particular statistic directly?

Comment: Almost certainly. Remember, [the single biggest group of deletionists are the authors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296608/what-posts-get-deleted-and-why)

Comment: Stats for deletions by third parties would be great.