# why The tooltip is telling you it is loading when the answer was accepted?

Tags: bug, accepted-answer, tooltips

- Click this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50596927/2218635)
- Hover the mouse without any shakes in accept answer icon
- You can see this `loading when this answer was accepted` tool tip

[image]

- This tool tip staying long period (but if you shake your mouse then the correct tool tip is coming).
- If you do hover again then only we can see the accepted time details tool tip.

**Note:** If you are not able to see this tool tip, please do refresh the browser and check. it's shows only one time after refreshed the browser.

Comment: I don't understand this bug report...

Comment: @SurajRao did you see `loading when this answer was accepted` tooltip?

Comment: actually no.. also I didnt get the steps you took to get that.. nor what its supposed to show. I may just need coffee. I dont know

Comment: I saw it briefly.  *Briefly*.  It's since gone away, so I'm tempted to blame caching for this one.

Comment: OH!  The tool tip coming on first time after the browser refreshing.

Comment: still i can see that. May be you guys are checking without browser refresh.

Comment: So the tooltip tells you exactly what is happening. I don't call that a bug.

Comment: @S.L.Barth .  the issue is `This tool tip staying long period` without showing the correct tool tip

Comment: It stays until you shake your mouse? Good. A tool tip that gives me time to read it. Sorry, it's not a bug in my book.

Comment: I am not sure. Why it's going negative votes.

Comment: It's really bad in my mind. this below answer explained this issue/feature. but other guys are voted to off topic because `unable to reproduce it` . Good

Comment: I don't know about _no repro_ reason but I definitely think this is a non-issue...

Comment: As a webdev, you might've noticed that this tip is generated by setting the title attribute. When that's dynamically changed, the web browser won't update it on screen if it's already displaying. If you think that's a bug, contact the browser manufacturer (but afaik it's standard behavior and all browsers share it).

Comment: This is a funny one.

Comment: [Don't use incorrect closevotes as "disagree" votes please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336622/can-we-talk-about-the-reviewing-culture-here-on-meta).

Comment: @CodeCaster In defense of at least *some* close-voters, they really may not have been ale to reproduce the problem. A) The question doesn't really describe well how to reproduce the problem (importantly, it does not state that the accept marker must be hovered prior to the page being ready, or that you are more likely to see this if you have a slow internet connection/computer); and B) They may have fast internet connections and/or fast computers which make reproducing difficult, at best. For at least the later close-voters, they should have read the comments and answer which do explain this.

Comment: I [can't reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tFZA.png) the described issue. The tooltip is [rendering just fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tFZA.png)

Answer (score 9):

I finally get it after a strong cup of coffee... The tooltip is telling you it is *loading when the answer was accepted*. It is literally loading the piece of information which it shows later as tooltip.

The issue is what is it supposed to show while it is loading? I don't see this as a bug. It is just a feature when the loading is slow.

Tooltips don't get updated when they are rendered. Hover over the red square a few times to see the tooptip update, but only after you re-hover the div.

```js
let i = 0;
setInterval(() => document.getElementById("tooltipped").title = i++, 500);
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

div:hover{
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="tooltipped"></div>
```

Comment: I'll say thanks for your coffee. So my suggestion is why we can update the tool tip dynamically instead of hover again to get the accepted time?

Comment: you mentioned it happens when you refresh.. Even this information must be downloaded when the page is loaded. Obviously it is coming later than expected for you and not when you hover

Comment: This I believe is browser behavior: the tooltip text won't update when the tooltip is already shown and the `title` attribute is changed then.

Comment: That's sound was good.  So we can't  see the `loading when the answer was accepted` tool tip  after the fixes??

Comment: @RameshRajendran That's a feature of browser stock tooltips. Once shown, they are not changed until re-shown. There's nothing that Stack Exchange can do about that. It would be possible for them to implement their own tooltip, but I don't see any compelling reason for them to do so.

Comment: @Makyen No. This issue not related with browser behavior. We should load the information on page load time as same as hover time.

Comment: As per my knowledge the  if hover function is called in page load event. then the error/ feature request should gone.

Comment: @RameshRajendran to reproduce this behaviour you had to hover as soon as the page is loaded... The info is received on page load already

Comment: BTW: The URL from which to tooltip is fetched is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50596927/accepted-answer-date). There's quite a bit which Stack Exchange pages do as part of their loading process. Very little on the page is functional until all the assets are loaded and the JavaScript runs, including a variety of AJAX calls to fill in information which isn't in the initial HTML  page delivered.

Comment: @SurajRao Nope. I waited  few seconds after the page load. Now also I can see that tool tip

Comment: @RameshRajendran do you have a proposal for what the accepted behaviour should look like ? What should it show during data load?

Comment: @SurajRao Yup. We won't to see the `loading when the answer was accepted` tool tip. Because it won't update automatically. So remove the tool tip and we should shows the  `The question owner accepted this as the best answer 1 hour ago`  tool tip  **always**.

Comment: Why should SO delay the entire render just to wait for a tooltip that will most likely already be loaded 99% of the time someone hovers it?

Comment: @RameshRajendran I should have been more precise. The data for that tooltip is loaded only once it's needed. This is determined by you mousing over the element (i.e. not necessarily upon page-load). This is a normal thing for SE pages to do. There are other tooltips, and other information, like this, which isn't loaded until it might be needed. Thus, if your network is quite slow, it's possible for the loading tooltip to be shown after the page is completely loaded, if your network connection is unable to get the data from SE in time to display the tooltip (usually > 500ms).